# Gmail undo yellow notification area disappears too rapidly on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, notifications

I'm having trouble with the Gmail yellow notification area disappearing too quickly in Google Chrome. For reference, I am talking about the notification that appears at the top of Gmail after archiving or deleting a message from a web browser.

I tried it on IE9 and it works fine. I have also cleared the cache and cookies on Chrome and the issue persists. Has anybody run into this on Chrome and know of a solution?

Comment: Chrome is executing the JavaScript code GMail is sending to it, I cannot see why it should execute it "faster" than IE. Sounds more an issue with the GMail itself.

Comment: In IE, the notification does not disappear at all. It's not a matter of it executing faster, the notification disappears in Chrome.

Comment: What happens when you change (increase) Gmail's timeout?      Go to "settings" (it's in the menu under the six-lobed gear icon, upper right side of Gmail's web client.  Choose "settings" and on the first tab, called "General", the 6th item is the one you want:  It's called "Undo timeout".  It defaults to 10 seconds, but could be 5, 20 or 30 seconds.

Comment: I don't have "Undo timeout" but I had "Undo send" because of a Gmail Lab. I set it to the max (30s) and I also tried disabling it altogether. Same problem still...

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension was the cause of this. The specific extension was called Any.DO. Disabling the extension restored the Gmail undo yellow notification.